# Vulnerability found on GIMP 2.8.14 (Windows)

Tags: windows, security, gimp

I have advised of a security issue found on the software GIMP 2.8.14. The vulnerability description can be found here: [Vulnerability Description](https://www.debian.org/security/2016/dsa-3612)

And the CVE here: [CVE-2016-4994](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2016-4994)

When I was advised of the vulnerability, I also was advised about a solution, which is update the software with a particular version sent to me in that advise. The thing is that the upgrade is available only for linux, and we have GIMP on Windows.

Do you know something about the risks of this vulnerability on 2.8.16 version (which is the one that we have)? And if there are risks, do you know the proper actions to avoid that?

I haven't found anything about GIMP on Windows, all the solutions are set for Linux.

Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new version 2.8.18 of GIMP fixes this vulnerability. Check the releaase notes at: http://www.gimp.org/news/2016/07/14/gimp-2-8-18-released/

However, I don'think that is a big issue at all.

GIMP is not meant to be "secure software" - it runs as a user processor, and have to deal with tens of file formats, each one able to have up to hundreds of different data structures. It uses third-party libraries to handle some of those data formats.

One can't expect any version of GIMP to be secure against opening a file and have that file execute arbitrary code, with the same privileges the program itself has. While this particular vulnerability tells about GIMP's native XCF files, which may be fixed in that respect, one can simply open a postscript file, which is by definition a complete program - and *will* run arbitrary code, even for well-formed images. In most cases, the postcript libraries in use should sandbox the running program and prevent it from accessing, say, the filesystem, but it will be able to use CPU as a DoS attack nevertheless.

It is up to your OS to control what resources an user application can access. Vulnerabilities in GIMP won't offer privilege escalation, if the OS is tight. And one could even use finer grained security features (e.g. SELinux) to further restrict application access.

As for GIMP, the 2.8.18 version is out as of yesterday - if this particular issue is marked as fixed, you should try to grab that one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll try to follow your recomendations related with the assurance of the OS, as well as the 2.8.18 version thing. The problem that we have ensuring the OS is that is a Windows, not Linux, and the managment of that OS at a lower or restrictive level is more complex than Linux. Maybe upgrade our version will be a better and achievable solution. Thanks again.